# plotOutput / uiOutput generate over-height plots that exceed the `fluidRow()` in shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

In my `shiny` app, I want that a line of text always stays at the bottom of the page. Therefore, I used two `fluidRow()`s to build the UI, the upper row shows the page, and the lower row for the text. However, the plot I generated is over-height, and overlapped with my bottom text.

[image]

Here's the example code that reproduces the error.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      navbarPage(
        "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "Widgets",
          fluidRow(column(12, actionButton("draw", "Draw!"), style = "height:88vh;"))
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "Plots",
          fluidRow(column(12, uiOutput("Plot"), style = "height:88vh;"))
          # I used the `uiOutput()` because in my actual case I want to show multiple plots in a navlistPanel() with many tabs.
          # both `plotOutput()` and `uiOutput()` will trigger the error.
        )
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(column(12, p("here's the bottom text", style = "text-align:center;")))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$draw, {
      output$p1 <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + geom_point()
      }, height = 1200)
      
      output$Plot <- renderUI({plotOutput("p1")})
      
    })
  }
)
```

All I expected is that the row of text always stays at the bottom of the page, no matter how long the plot is. What did I do wrong? And what should I do?

Comment: You can't use `height = 1200` for the plot and at the same time `style = "height:88vh;` for the `fluidRow` which carries the `uiOutput` for the plot. Set it e.g. to `style = height:1200px;` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Jan, I came up with a solution that reactively renders the Page:

- at the initial launch of shiny app, the upper row shows a `div` with 88% height.
- once triggered the event button, the upper row will render a picture with unlimited height.

```r
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      navbarPage(
        "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "Widgets",
          fluidRow(column(12, actionButton("draw", "Draw!"), style = "height:88vh;"))
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "Plots",
          fluidRow(column(12, uiOutput("Plot")))
        )
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(12, p("here's the bottom text", style = "text-align:center;"))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    init.p <- reactiveVal(0)
    
    observeEvent(input$draw, {init.p(init.p() + 1)})
    
    plotpage <- reactive({
      init <- init.p()
      
      if (init == 0) {
        return(tagList(div(style = "height:88vh;width:100%")))
      } else {
        return(
          renderPlot({
            ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + geom_point()
          }, height = 1200)
        )
      }
    })

    output$Plot <- renderUI({plotpage()})
  }
)
```